# I have another question that needs re-opening

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Sorry about this, but someone closed another one of my questions: https://askubuntu.com/q/230012/95681

I don't get why it's "Too Localized" - I'm using the included, default torrent program, on the LTS release. Nothing funky or unusual.

If I pick the close reason apart, it only shows that my question was closed completely unjustly:

> **closed as too localized by [qbi](https://askubuntu.com/users/236/qbi), [Eric Carvalho](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho), [Luis Alvarado♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/7035/luis-alvarado), [hhlp](https://askubuntu.com/users/3550/hhlp), [LnxSlck](https://askubuntu.com/users/49189/lnxslck) Feb 14 at 11:40**
>
> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#close).

*[...]only relevant to a small geographic area[...]*
This has nothing to do with geography. If I fly my computer to Europe, that's not going to fix anything.

*[...]specific moment in time[...]*
Nope, tried it again the next day. Didn't work. Week later, nothing. Next month? (You'll never guess: NOTHING.)

*[...]or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet[....]*
What, Ubuntu users don't make torrents? If anything at all can be considered as "generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet", Torrents are it.

..anyway, I'd like this to be reconsidered. Was there something wrong with the title? Did I phrase something in a way that irritated someone in a high place? The close reason is completely invalid, and no comments were provided as to why it was closed. (I know that sometimes "Too Localized" can be used as a Reason to close a question, if the actual reason was not an option for Closing..)

Comment: Done. I saw the images and yes it is weird. I made a comment on your question to get more information.

Comment: Remember, if you want to quickly ask informally, feel free to do so in chat.

Comment: On the other hand, it wasn't a very good question imho. No explanation/mention of what you used (only some screenshots, but you could at least _mention_ the program and steps you used). This question also has a lot of indignation in it. Relax, maybe someone made a mistake. no need to go all `someone in a high place` etc.

Comment: @Nanne Well, I'm actually quite indignant about the closure! I'm using the default torrent application, Transmission, which I freely mentioned, as soon as someone pointed out I left out that information. _However_, that (relatively) insignificant mistake should have caused the question to be closed as low quality, and not "too localized".

Comment: You could just disagree and start this topic (you did) and let the indignation be. It helps for random passer-bys to actually see your case instead of thinking you're coming across a bit rude. No offense meant, it just seems counterproductive for you. Besides that, meta isn't for letting of steam :)

Comment: @Nanne Okay, very well put.

Answer (score 3):

If it seems incredibly likely it's an unlikely user error, then unlikely to be useful to future visitors covers user error.

Just putting in my soon to be heavily down-voted (probably) two cents.

Alternately, it could be a linking to outside the target folder bug.  In which case it should still be closed.  Just as a bug instead of as not useful.

Comment: Perfectly valid, and in my opinion all that was needed was a comment to accompany the closure.